# Javascript : Change Div Length

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change the div length and am using this code but it's not working. Please help me out. I am doing this through javascript.

```
function upBig()
{
var len = document.getElementById('div');

var h = parseInt(len.style.height);

var a = 10;

len.style.height = h-a+"px"; 
}
```

Comment: I mean are you ever calling your function?

Comment: yes, I was doing that in html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function upBig(id,ud) {
       var div=document.getElementById(id);
       var h=parseInt(div.style.height)+ud;
       if (h>=1){
          div.style.height = h + "px";
       }
    }

<div style="background:red;height:250px" id="div">HELLO 250px</div>
<div>  
  <input type="button" value="- 10 px" onclick="upBig('div', -10);">
  <input type="button" value="+ 10 px" onclick="upBig('div', +10);">
</div>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/1cotj5o5/60/)**

Note : you can change the values of course by what you want

Comment: Then give more details, your question is how to change the length of the div.. and my answer does it

Comment: That's why i posted what i have written I meant that a specific lenght is given and i want to either reduce it or increase it by clicking on given button in html

Comment: Okay, I just figured out, check my edited answer, if it's not what you want, I really don't know then.

Answer (score 0):

The height property returns value in px so this should work

```
len.style.height = (parseInt(h)-a)+"px";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function upBig() {
    var e = document.querySelector('#div'); // *1
    e.style.height = (parseInt(e.style.height || e.clientHeight(), 10) - 10).toString() + 'px';
}
```

Your code didn't work, since `element.style.height` only reads the height if it is set in the elements style attribute, which is often not the case. `clientHeight()` get's what is actually the height of the element as shown to the user.

*1 - There may be a compatibility issue for some older browsers, check that this function is compatible with all browsers you wish to target ([compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#search=querySelector))

Answer (score -1):

```
function upBig()
{
    var div=document.getElementById('div');
    var a = 10;

    var h=parseInt(div.style.height)+a;
    div.style.height = h + "em"; // I'm using "em" instead of "px", but you can use px like measure...
}
```